# Google Map flickering in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.10.17867.0 in my app via pod. But when I initialise the map at a particular position, all the titles and map starts flickering.
Example Code (swift):

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(19.0176147, longitude: 72.8561644, zoom:18) 
    // even try this: 28.6469655, longitude: 77.0932634, zoom:10 
    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:camera)

    var marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = camera.target
    marker.snippet = "Hello World"
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    marker.map = mapView

    self.view = mapView
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no issue in your code, you should try different simulators or devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the reason.

If you are using an incorrect google maps api key, or correct key with insufficient permissions, then this will happen. It was the latter reason for us.

For further reading, [documentation link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#step_4_enable_the_required_apis_on_the_console_name), although the said behaviour is not mentioned anywhere. It should rather log an error message.

Comment: Very late comment. I followed a tutorial from youtube and the reason why my google map was flickering every time the coordinates changed was because I used `view = googleMapView` inside the `didUpdateLocations` function. What you need to do is make a static map, add this to the view. then you can play around with markers and userLocation inside the map, inside the `didUpdateLocations` function. Just like how you would do it for iOS native map.