# Google maps blinking (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have `UITabBarController` with two view controllers: map and something else. Each time when I choose ViewController with google maps on the tabbar, map blinks (rendering). Can I somehow turn off this behaviour?

Comment: You might be initialising the Map everytime.. do it on viewDidLoad.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Just create storyboard with tabbar - two view controllers in them (map and another controller). In first controller add GMSMapView as subview. There is no any code. Only storyboard.

Comment: check this  [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801951/google-map-flickering-in-ios-via-pod)